# Javascript and HTML defer tag not working

Tags: javascript, html, deferred

The Javascript function below works perfectly when at the bottom of html file. However, I need it in main.js file. It has been suggested that adding the defer tag to the script tag will enable this but unfortunately not. It prints the first console.log but then stops. Any suggestions?

```
<script src="/static/main.js" defer></script>
```

```
// function to add items to shopping
let cartbutton = document.getElementsByName('ropebutton');
console.log(cartbutton) // prints node []
const cart = [];
    
for(var i = 0; i < cartbutton.length; i++) {
    let button = cartbutton[i];
    console.log(button); // doesn't print
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.clear();
        console.log(event.target);
        console.log(event.target.dataset.test);
        cart.push(event.target.dataset.test);
        console.log(cart)            
    });
};
```

````
<div class="column">
        <img src="static/111.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope111" id="rope111" name="ropebutton" onclick="addcart(this.value);" type="submit">$4,500 buy</button>
        <img src="static/112.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope112" id="rope112" name="ropebutton" type="submit">$3,500 buy</button>
        <img src="static/113.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope113" id="rope113" name="ropebutton" type="button">$1,550 buy</button>
    </div>```
````

Comment: This is the best I can do with the information you have given, but it's worth a shot: try wrapping it in a [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event).

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code? I mean the one having the elements with `ropebutton` as name attribute value

Comment: I've added the buttons that I'm referencing. As I say though, it works perfectly when at the bottom of the html file. It's very strange that the defer tag doesn't work.

Comment: I've tried the DOMContentLoaded and it didn't work. I posted a question on here and it was suggested to use the defer tag.

Comment: What do you mean by stops? Showing any errors? What about `node []`? Do you mean it's empty?

Comment: The function stops. I have lots of console.logs and only the first one will print. No errors are showing. If I pressed a button nothing happens so node [] remains empty.

Comment: When I put the script at the bottom of html file, node[] will populate as I press the buttons, but not in main.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two methods to have your code executed after loading the HTML content and to avoid blocking the render of the page. Either reference your script at the end of your `<body>` tag or in `<head>` but with `defer` attribute.

You can try referencing the script at the end of your `<body>` tag like this:

```
<bod>
    <div class="column">
        <img src="static/111.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope111" id="rope111" name="ropebutton" onclick="addcart(this.value);" type="submit">$4,500 buy</button>
        <img src="static/112.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope112" id="rope112" name="ropebutton" type="submit">$3,500 buy</button>
        <img src="static/113.jpg" alt="Rope" class="imgsize">
        <button class="btn btn-dark" data-test="rope113" id="rope113" name="ropebutton" type="button">$1,550 buy</button>
    </div>

    <script src="/static/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I can't see any issues in your JS code that prevent you from using either methods

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Really appreciated. I may put it at the end of all the html files that require it, changing the identifier for each, and somehow getting the information together afterwards. Maybe my best option.

Comment: Glad, I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Previous poster corrected this. I did as Fadi said and put the following at the end of every html file that needed it:

`<script src="/static/main.js" defer></script>`

I hadn't realised you can use it multiple times. Thank you Fadi Hania.